# How to move Lines continuously in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cordova

I'm beginner in HTML5 canvas game development. I am trying to create one simple game which contains two lines and one character((example car)) in the middle. when player slide the devices then character(example car) should move left and right by using accelometer in Phonegap, I got the co-ordinates and done character movement according to accelometer. The problem is line movements continuously according to character(example car).
Till now I have tried like this, please have look on my code.

HTML file

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Adding viewport -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_v1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/acelometer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="can" style="position: fixed;"> </canvas>
<div id="accelerometer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript file

```
var watchID = null;
var can;
var context;
var canvasX;
var canvasY;
var x, y;
var mousePosX, mousePosY;
var canInnerWidth, canInnerHeight;
var cx1 = 0, cy1 = 0;
var lwx1, lwx2, lhy1, lhy2, rwx3, rwx4, rhy3, rhy4;
var car = new Image();
car.src = "img/car.jpg";
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
init();
startWatch();
}
function init() {

can = document.getElementById('can');
context = can.getContext('2d');

can.width = can.parentNode.clientWidth;
can.height = can.parentNode.clientHeight;
// circle coordinates
cx1 = can.width / 2;
cy1 = can.height - can.height / 9;
console.log("Circle x co-ordinates :" + cx1);
console.log("Circle y co-ordinates :" + cy1);

// for lines co-ordiantes
lwx1 = can.width / 3;
lwx2 = 0;
lhy1 = 0;
lhy2 = can.height - can.height / 10;
// right
rwx3 = can.width - can.width / 3;
rwx4 = can.width;
rhy3 = 0;
rhy4 = can.height - can.height / 10;
console.log("canvas width :" + can.width);
console.log("canvas height :" + can.height);

initialLines();
//drawCircle();
   }
   function initialLines() {
can.width = can.width;
// left side..
context.strokeStyle = 'green';
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(can.width / 3, 0);
context.lineTo(0, can.height - can.height / 10);
context.stroke();

// right..
context.strokeStyle = 'green';
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(can.width - can.width / 3, 0);
context.lineTo(can.width, can.height - can.height / 10);
context.stroke();

  }
  function drawImagess() {
context.drawImage(car, cx1, cy1);

 }
 function redrawCircle(cx1, cy1, j) {
var radius = 7;
can.width = can.width;
initialLines();
context.beginPath();
context.arc(cx1, cy1, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = 'blue';
context.fill();
context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
context.stroke();
   }
    function drawNewLinesOnRightSide(rwx4, lwx2, lhy2, cx1) {
can.width = can.width;
context.drawImage(car, cx1, cy1);
context.strokeStyle = 'green';

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(rwx3, rhy3);
context.lineTo(rwx4, rhy4);
context.stroke();
context.strokeStyle = 'green';
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(lwx1, lhy1);
context.lineTo(lwx2, lhy2);
context.stroke();   
  }
  function drawNewLinesOnLeftSide(lwx2, rwx4, rhy4, cx1){   
can.width = can.width;
context.drawImage(car, cx1, cy1);
context.strokeStyle = 'green';
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(lwx1, 0);
context.lineTo(lwx2, lhy2);
context.stroke();

context.strokeStyle = 'green';
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(rwx3, 0);
context.lineTo(rwx4, rhy4);
context.stroke();

 }
 // Start watching the acceleration

 function startWatch() {

// Update acceleration every 3 seconds
var options = {
    frequency : 1000
};

watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError,
        options);
 }

 // Stop watching the acceleration

  function stopWatch() {
if (watchID) {
    navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(watchID);
    watchID = null;
} 
  }

 // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current acceleration
 //
 function onSuccess(acceleration) {

var can = document.getElementById('can');
var context = can.getContext('2d');
var element = document.getElementById('accelerometer');
element.innerHTML = 'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '<br />'
        + 'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '<br />'
        + 'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '<br />' + 'Timestamp: '
        + acceleration.timestamp + '<br />';

if(acceleration.y > 0 && acceleration.y < 2){
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    can.width = can.width;
    drawNewLinesOnRightSide(rwx4, lwx2, lhy2, cx1);
    context.drawImage(car, cx1, cy1);
    cx1++;
    rwx4 -= 2;
    lwx2 += 1;
    lhy2 -= 2;

    }
}else if(acceleration.y > 2 && acceleration.y < 10){
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    can.width = can.width;
    drawNewLinesOnRightSide(rwx4, lwx2, lhy2, cx1);
    context.drawImage(car, cx1, cy1);
    cx1 += 3;
    rwx4 -= 2;
    lwx2 += 1;
    lhy2 -= 2;

    }
}else if(acceleration.y < 0 && acceleration.y > -2){
        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            can.width = can.width;
            drawNewLinesOnLeftSide(rwx4, lwx2, lhy2, cx1);
            context.drawImage(car, cx1, cy1);
            cx1--;  
            lwx2 += 2;
            rwx4 -= 3;
            rhy4 -= 4;
    }
}else if(acceleration.y < -2 && acceleration.y > -10){
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        can.width = can.width;
        drawNewLinesOnLeftSide(lwx2, rwx4, rhy4, cx1);
        context.drawImage(car, cx1, cy1);
        cx1 -= 3;
        lwx2 += 2;
        rwx4 -= 3;
        rhy4 -= 4;
    }
}
```

Please see the below reference link.
I am trying to develop game as same as this http://www.digyourowngrave.com/vector-runner/

Comment: It looks like it should already from what I can tell... It adds to the x and y of the lines when the acceleration changes... What issue are you running into?

Comment: @Zeaklous Sir, thanks for reply.. Its adding when acceleration changes but lines are crossing the canvas boundaries and how to stop drawing the lines when lines reaches the specified boundary. If u don't mind. can u please add the code for line movement according to acceleration(only Y axis in landscape mode). Please save life sir

Comment: To restrict the movement of the lines past a certain point you should create a variable to keep track of it, something like `var distanceFromStart = 0;` and inside of the accelerations add the change in x, something like `distanceFromStart += 1;` or whatever you have the values set to. Then you use if statements to prevent movement if the current value is equal to/above your max or equal to/below your min

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for replying. I have checked with all the possibilities with different type of condition but couldn't work. I am not getting where am I doing wrong. Finally I am moving lines with some fixed co-ordinates, its not a efficiency, check my code here http://pastie.org/8346631, I can't create Fiddle because of accelometer. I want to move lines like vector runner game http://www.digyourowngrave.com/vector-runner/ with Y axis in accelometer. Tomorrow is deadline for doing this game play. Can u please move the lines like that game?? Please help me sir. Thanks in advance